# Limit number of calls of function in JS, then return to a value that is not the starting value

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am involved writing JS for a martingale style gambling game. I created a loop script. The idea is the game is 50/50 chance and probability resets on each spin of the wheel. You make a bet higher/lower. I set up a script to double down on my losses and reset to my original bid on my wins. But I wanted to create a max_bet limit because you lose all your money on those higher spins. 10 straight losses = losing 1023X you original bid if you double each loss.

So the script below has a stop in place on the 7th loss (if(multiplyCalls < 5) Please note 5 because 0 is the start and also you need to include the losing 7th bid without a double bid effort. So essentially what ever value you put it goes +2. Sorry that is technical but just explains why it is 5 instead of 7.

However, I am seeing this have negative effects with it dropping all the way back to the original bid when it hits the max loss. It is on those higher spins that so much money is bet. I would like to modify this script to have it go back 3 bids instead of all the way back to 0. I just can't figure out how to set up the call.

```
var startValue = '0.00000001', // Don't lower the decimal point more than 4x of current balance
    stopPercentage = 0.001, // In %. I wouldn't recommend going past 0.08
    maxWait = 777, // In milliseconds
    stopped = false,
    stopBefore = 1; // In minutes
    multiplyCalls = 0; // <--- Added this global

var $loButton = $('#double_your_btc_bet_lo_button'),
            $hiButton = $('#double_your_btc_bet_hi_button');


function multiply(){
    if(multiplyCalls < 5){ // this sets the losses allowed, apply +2 (5 = 7 losses allowed)
        var current = $('#double_your_btc_stake').val();
        var multiply = (current * 2).toFixed(8);
        $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(multiply);
        multiplyCalls++; // increment
    }else{
        reset();
        console.log('=== RESETING ===');
    }
}

function getRandomWait(){
    var wait = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWait ) + 100;

    console.log('Waiting for ' + wait + 'ms before next bet.');

    return wait ;
}

function startGame(){
    console.log('Game started!');
    reset();
    $loButton.trigger('click');
}

function stopGame(){
    console.log('Game will stop soon! Let me finish.');
    stopped = true;
}

function reset(){
    $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(startValue);

}

// quick and dirty hack if you have very little bitcoins like 0.0000001
function deexponentize(number){
    return number * 1000000;
   }

   function iHaveEnoughMoni(){
    var balance = deexponentize(parseFloat($('#balance').text()));
    var current = deexponentize($('#double_your_btc_stake').val());

    return ((balance*2)/100) * (current*2) > stopPercentage/100;
   }

   function stopBeforeRedirect(){
    var minutes = parseInt($('title').text());

    if( minutes < stopBefore )
    {
            console.log('Approaching redirect! Stop the game so we don\'t get redirected while loosing.');
            stopGame();

            return true;
    }

    return false;
   }

   // Unbind old shit
  $('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').unbind();
  $('#double_your_btc_bet_win').unbind();

   // Loser
   $('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
    if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("lose")') )
    {
            console.log('You LOST! Multiplying your bet and betting again.');

            multiply();

            setTimeout(function(){
                    $loButton.trigger('click');
            }, getRandomWait());

            //$loButton.trigger('click');
    }
});

   // Winner
   $('#double_your_btc_bet_win').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
    if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("win")') )
    {
            if( stopBeforeRedirect() )
            {
                    return;
            }

            if( iHaveEnoughMoni() )
            {
                    console.log('You WON! But don\'t be greedy. Restarting!');

                    reset();

                    if( stopped )
                    {
                            stopped = false;
                            return false;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    console.log('You WON! Betting again');
            }

            setTimeout(function(){
                    $loButton.trigger('click');
            }, getRandomWait());
            multiplyCalls = 0; // reset value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more of a logic question than a JS one, but...

If I understand correctly, you want to record the value of the bet at the 4th bet (which in your code means at `multiplyCalls === 2`, right?). If so, set up a variable at the top called `maxBet` to hold that info.

In your `multiply` function, you can write to `maxBet` when the `multiplyCalls == 2` and then check if `maxBet > multiply` (once you've worked that out.

e.g.

```
var maxBet = 0;

function multiply(){
    if(multiplyCalls < 5){ // this sets the losses allowed, apply +2 (5 = 7 losses allowed)
        var current = $('#double_your_btc_stake').val();

        if(multiplyCalls === 2){
            maxBet = current;
        }

        var multiply = (current * 2).toFixed(8);

        if (multiply > maxBet) {
            multiple = maxBet;
        }

        $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(multiply);
        multiplyCalls++; // increment
    }else{ 
        reset();
        console.log('=== RESETING ===');
    }
}
```

Is this what you mean? If not, I hope it gets you a bit closer!

Comment: P.S. I wouldn't have a variable inside the function `multiply` called `multiply` - this will eventually make you into a gibbering wreck of a person.

Comment: I applied this and worked through some reference errors but it did not effectively return the bid to the fourth bid. Must not be recognizing maxBet. I started with a bid of 1 and had the cut off at 7. It went, 1,2,4,8,16,32,1,2. I should have gone 1,2,4,8,16,32,8,16.

Comment: Have you created the `maxBet` variable at the top of your script? If not, it won't update and be available the next time you call that function.